# PostGIS st_transform not working as expected

Tags: qgis, postgis, pyqgis

I am trying to write script about transform coordinates in PyQGIS. I am working on geopackage. When I create geometry with st_transform, coordinates will move right side with same distance. Not transformed geometry's SRID and desired SRID can be same. Here an example:

```
AsGPB(st_transform(GeomFromEWKT('SRID=5253;POINT(-2217885.89475928433239460 -45973.46579360473697307 0.00000000000000000)'),5253))
```

[image]

Comment: why are you transforming it from 5253 to 5253?

Comment: Actually I am trying to transform x to y. But example is in same srid.

Comment: you could transform to wgs84 to get the decimal degrees, then get those coordinates into your target layer by doing a join from the new layer. Be careful of how the data is transformed, and if you actually just want decimal degree values, or if you want the data actually transformed using a custom projection into wgs84 as I believe the default transformation to wgs84 for this projection is null.

Comment: where does postgis come into this process?